들어가며 as an introduction or preface
I am reading a book called 왜 아가리로만 할까?, where the first sentence of the book said

들어가며 책은 당신의 인생을 책임져주지 않는다


Once I asked a Korean acquaintance , he suggested that 들어가며 used ‘Intro’ over here, but I did not get a chance to ask him in further details…
It is my understanding that 들어가다 implies to go in or to enter, whereas 며 seems to come from (으)면서. Hence it is correct to assume that 들어가며 here just means “while/upon entering (or starting this book)” and the whole sentence is actually a preface of this book or does 들어가며 has any deeper meaning that?

It must be understood as "들어가며" as a separate heading (i.e., the title of the current section), followed by a complete sentence, "책은 당신의 인생을 책임져주지 않는다."  If you connect the two, the resulting sentence doesn't make much sense.
Seen this way, "들어가며" literally means "entering," that is, "as we enter this book."  So, interpreting it as "Preface" is a perfectly good translation.
So it could be translated as:

Preface
Books cannot take care of your life for you.


By the way, this is completely unrelated to the question (so feel free to disregard), but I have to point out that 아가리 is a really rude word when used for a person's mouth - if you use it for anyone near you, you'll be starting a fight.  I can't believe someone is writing a book with that kind of title, and I'd be wary of using such a book to learn Korean: I wouldn't trust the author to use proper Korean phrases.
